# Element is undefined Javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Element.prototype.hasClassName = function (a) {
    return new RegExp("(?:^|\\s+)" + a + "(?:\\s+|$)").test(this.className);
};
```

can any ine tell me how to define this element

- In my IE11 i am constantly getting error that it is undefined in my
  utils.js file

Comment: how to find it how is it used just came accross this issue dont know how it is used as

Comment: How is it related to jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

In modern browsers you could better rely on the [`classList` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList):

```
el.classList.contains( 'myclass' ); // returns true or false
```

For older browser [MDN lists a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList#wrapper).

Comment: how to define that el

Comment: @dennis Like you get a hold of any other element: `document.getElementById()`, `document.querySelector()`,... Whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has a distinction between `native objects` -- those things created by JavaScript and `host objects` -- those things created by the browser for JavaScript to use.

The rules on how the two behave are quite different, but to summarize:

1. Don't extend host objects.
2. Don't try to access host objects in any way not advertised
3. Don't trust them to behave.

`Element` is a host object, and under IE, doesn't follow the typical prototype behavior.